How to install Laravel Breeze with TypeScript?
I try to install Laravel Breeze with React, Inertia, and TypeScript like this:
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
php artisan breeze:install

but have a problem. I select TypeScript as "optional feature" but it still proceed as if I didn't select any. I even try to add a flag "--typescript" but I got no success. There are no errors, just no TypeScript in there.
PHP 8.3.8 Laravel 11.22.0

The problem is when it is a list to select optional feature one have to select them with "space" bar before using "enter" as for other options.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/50773
